# How do I pass a platform-specific string (a path) in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I have a database that could be stored in different places depending on the platform. For example, for Xamarin.Mac, the database is stored in @executable_path/../Resources/my.db. Right now the ViewModel handles initializing the database, and I'm happy to leave it there. However, I need to pass it a path and all I see is

```
var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
startup.Start ();
```

in the AppDelegate. In Mvx I have been using RegisterSingleton and Resolve, but I'm not sure I should be using that for a simple string (should I have IMyDbPath and MyDbPath interface and class?) Looking for an elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the MvvmCross-SQLite-Net plugin.  Once it's registered, either manually or by the Bootstrap there will be two interfaces you can resolve:

`ISQLiteConnectionFactory` or `ISQLiteConnectionFactoryEx`

When you resolve `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` you'll be able to call `Create(string address)` passing the path to your database.  The path you give `Create` is not platform specific, meaning, `Create` will figure out the platform specific base path for you.

```
 private ISQLiteConnection CreateFileDb(SQLiteConnectionOptions options)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.Address))
                throw new ArgumentException(Properties.Resources.CreateFileDbInvalidAddress);
            var path = options.BasePath ?? GetDefaultBasePath();
            string filePath = LocalPathCombine(path, options.Address);
            return CreateSQLiteConnection(filePath, options.StoreDateTimeAsTicks);
        }
```

So you could pass `MyDatabase.db` or `data/MyDatabase.db` on the supported platforms and it should resolve the base path for you.